# Can I get LiveView from my Nikon Coolpix P600 on my computer?

Tags: nikon, tethering, coolpix

I want to be able to view what I am shooting on my  Nikon Coolpix P600  camera  on my computer before I take. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called **tethering**.

As far as I know, no camera from the Nikon Coolpix Pxxx line can be tethered.

- Lightroom doesn't support it : https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support.html
- The guys from controlmynikon.com aren't supporting it : http://www.controlmynikon.com/#!download/cdhg
- Same thing from digicamcontrol.com : http://digicamcontrol.com/cameras (only the control of some Coolpix - L830, 5400 and S5300 - is mentioned, but no Live view).

If you are not looking for *viewing then shooting* and can settle for *shooting manually then viewing*, you can use ViewNX2 from Nikon (http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/fr/products/166/ViewNX_2.html) or a wifi SD card if using a cable is an issue.

Mostly DSLR can be tethered.

Comment: You can make a try with digiCamControl more user reported that P600 can be controlled but only capture no liveview. Live view via usb isn't supported by the camera firmware