# Is tethering possible with the Nikon Coolpix P520?

Tags: nikon, tethering, live-view, windows, coolpix

### 1. Summary

I can't find, is it possible PC live view for Nikon Coolpix P520.

---

### 2. Details

I try to scan books, use this device. It would be nice to have feature, that user can to see on PC monitor, whether book pages are displayed well.

I want to have similar behavior as in this video:

- [**Youtube video**](https://youtu.be/KohJ2_XYpZU?t=183)

Windows 10 64-bit is my operating system.

---

### 3. Not helped

1. Google queries
2. [**Programs**](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/56/COOLPIX_P520.html) from Official Nikon download Center
3. [**digiCamControl**](http://digicamcontrol.com/cameras), [**ControlMyNikon**](https://www.tetherscript.com/controlmynikon-comparison/) and [**Lightroom**](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support.html) doesn't support this device

---

### 4. Related questions

- [**Can I get LiveView from my Nikon Coolpix P600 on my computer?**](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/79257/81094)
- [**Are there any free Windows programs to get a live view for a Nikon D700 in tethered capture mode?**](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/15383/81094)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get LiveView from my Nikon Coolpix P600 on my computer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/79257/can-i-get-liveview-from-my-nikon-coolpix-p600-on-my-computer)